# add or update node value with array php

Tags: php, xml, loops

Sorry for possible newbie question, but I need to use xml for an import. I've figured it out so far but then scratched my eyeballs out while trying to figure out this (and searched for it)

I have this

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$container = $xml-> createElement("container");
$container = $xml-> appendChild($container);


for($n=0;$n<8;$n++){
    $maxnum[]=$n;
}
$xtags = $xml->CreateElement("tags",$maxnum); $xtags = $container->appendChild($xtags);
if($xml->save("stuff2.xml")){echo 'success';} else {echo 'not working';}
?>
```

Basically I don`t want to create a child node for ever value of a loop. And I know that`s not the proper way to do it, nor is `array_values` and so on. But it's what I want to achieve. I need to generate an XML file for wpall import so that I can succesfully bulk import to woocommerce. The specific attribute here i ize, and I`m getting that using`file_get_contents` from the server, parsing which xpath with a foreach loop. Problem is I want them all in a single field rather than having this

```
<size>
<value>1</value>
<value>2</value>
</size>
```

and so on, when I want it like this `<size><value>1,2,3....</value></size>`

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you do not need to use an array,
you can do something like:

```
echo "<size><value>";
foreach($n as $n){
$string="$string, ".$n;
}
echo $string;
echo" </value></size>";
```

Comment: That makes sense, however, how would I put that into xml, from php? Because my issue is like this `$xtags = $xml->CreateElement("tags",$maxnum);` , where all the values of the loop need to be stored in just one node instead of separe ones
And it's not about getting it printed as the output, it's about transferring and being able to save in the xml doc. Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: '$xtags = $xml->CreateElement("value",$maxnum);'

if $maxnum is a string, instead of an array, should output:
<value>1,2,3....</value>

Comment: Here it is tested:
`
    <?php
    $n=array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    $maxnum=implode($n,",");

    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $value = $xml-> createElement("value");
    $xml-> appendChild($value);
    $size = $xml-> createElement("size",$maxnum);
    $value-> appendChild($size);
    print $xml->saveXML();
    ?>`

Comment: Tested, brilliant. Excuse my noobness while I implement and then research this further. Gave me a lot of trouble. Much appreciated!